# Visual Studio 2015 multiple uwp apps with same code

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I am trying to run multiple apps with the same code, the only differences are application names, icons and the splashscreen.

I am already 100 % sure that my approach must be complete crap, but here is my approach:

I copied the excisting project specific configuring files, changed all file names to the new project, replaced references inside these files and imported this project back to the solution, because creating a complete new product within the solutions ignores all yet created files so I wanted to save some time. Now have 1 solution (I thought of this as the product) and 1 projekt for each customer, all targets sharing all code, except the project configs with the ids, names and icons etc..

But when I try to build any of the project I get these errors

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: 
The process cannot access the file 
'C:\...\project.lock.json' 
because it is being used by another process.
```

Or the assembly is used by another application.

So, this can't be the right way to do what I want to do by Visual Studio, I'm looking for the right way to handle 1 base-product but many customer-specific-apps with Visual Studio 2015. 
Sadly I couldn't find any tutorial for that yet. 
Maybe I'm searching with the wrong description or naming, I thought of projects as targets in Xcode. 
A link to a proper tutorial would already do the job for me.
Thanks!

Comment: So you have 1 code-base, and literally the only thing that will change per customer is their configuration file and splash screen? Your question is "1 base-product but many customer-specific-apps". Why not just 1 base-project with the ability to be customized per customer through a simple configuration change? Or do customers need you to do customization for them each time?

Comment: Once my app is distributed to 1000+ customers, I don't want to change the app-icons, name etc every time I have to update their version. I want to be able to change a line of code once, and the customer specific changes stay in each config of the project ( if 1 project = 1 customer ).

Comment: So it sounds like you just need 1 config per customer. Not 1 project per customer. It's not hard to maintain a configuration file. How are you pushing updates at the moment? is there a database on the client-side?

Comment: Okay, that would be nice if I get that to work like this.
I'm providing the backend with a login and content. Customers have only a git access. If that is what your question is.

Comment: Just trying to figure out your current setup. So if you control the backend with login/content, you should be able to control the configuration on their side by making the app look (and save) the splash screen/name for the app on the client. you should be able to build a generic enough login screen for them so that when they login, your app checks for their configuration, if found / nothing changed, use that, else download new config

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, but some customers say they want their own icon, name etc, before the login, and that is what I want to manage in a smart way.
Once they log in, I am loading the userConfig, but that is too late for some of the customers...

Comment: As a first time setup, they login with a generic form. save the settings locally, next time they open the app, their own splash screen. make it part of the setup. Some companies white label like that.

Comment: Okay, I couldn't figure out yet how to easily change the Package.appxmanifest of the project with another Package.appxmanifest file, will I have to change it manually or do you know how to make that easier with visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I think what you want is building multiple branded apps from a single Visual Studio solution. If so, here is a nice article: [Multi-Branded Apps in Visual Studio (Windows 10 UWP)](http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1087) you can refer to.

The key point here is using separate build configurations for each app and then using Pre-build commands to create the app package.

For more info, please see [Understanding Build Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) and [Specifying Custom Build Events in Visual Studio](http://Specifying%20Custom%20Build%20Events%20in%20Visual%20Studio).

Comment: Awesome, that's it! Thank you so much!